# Cambiar permisos de carpetas compartidas con docker-compose

Tags: linux, bash, docker, permisos, docker-compose

**Escenario**

Tengo un docker-compose que me crea dos contenedores un `Prestashop` y otro con `mariaDB` .

---

**El problema**

El sistema funciona puedo acceder a los datos desde el contendor y a la aplicación. Pero las carpetas quedan como root y no puedo editar con `Atom` o bien no puedo acceder a la base de datos con `DBeaver` .

Lo puedo cambiar desde mi consola mediante el usuario Root. Pero no creo qeu se a lo correcto.

---

**Objetivo**

Que el propio docker-compose configure los permisos correctos para que se pueda acceder a lo carpetas compartidas desde diferentes aplicaciones así como desde los contenedores.

---

**Código**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: ps-mariadb
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
       - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: bash -c "cd /var/lib/ | chown -R www-data mysql/"  
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "PasswordRoot"
       MYSQL_DATABASE: "name_database"
       MYSQL_USER: "name_user"
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "Password"
    ports:
      - "3333:3306"
    expose:
      - "3333"
    networks:
      - my_net
    restart: on-failure

  ps:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: ps-web
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/html:/var/www/html"
    command: bash -c "cd /var/www/ | chown -R www-data html/"
    image: prestashop/prestashop:1.7-7.0
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      DB_SERVER: "db:3306"
      DB_USER: "ps"
      DB_PASSWD: "ps"
      DB_NAME: "ps"
    networks:
      - my_net
networks:
  my_net:
```

También he probado con estas variantes en el `command` ...

```
command: bash -c "cd $PWD | find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  | find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;"
```

---

**Dudas**

Tengo la duda de si es un error de sintaxis o bien de planeamiento.

*Gracias por la ayuda.*

### ---

**EDITO**

**Conseguida solución parcial**. Monte los directorios (`data` y `html`) de forma manual.

Ahora puedo editar el código con Atom sin problemas.

Pero no se puede acceder a la base de datos el `data\`

Desde DBeaver puedo ver las tablas pero a la hora de editar los registros devuelve:

> SQL Error [1932] [42S02]: (conn:12) Table 'spdshfwtpx.ps_shop_group'
>   doesn't exist in engine

Y Prestashop no consigue conectar ...

> Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   Connection refused

Pero esto puede ser por los permisos, pero igual porque no he conseguido editar la url del atienda en `ps_shop_url`.

*La base de datos alojada en el `data` es un copia del servidor. Puede ser que haya un conflicto con los permisos??*

Comment: ¿Cuál es el sistema operativo que utilizas actualmente?

Comment: En local tengo instalado Debian 9, el contenedor de Prestashop utiliza una imagen base con PHP-Apache2 que no se exactamente de diestro es. Pero por los comandos Debian o Ubuntu me imagino.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a que no puedes editar con Atom, es por que lanzas los contenedores para desarrollar (supongo). En este caso deberías crear un volumen que apunte a tu código y lo monte en el contenedor.

Comment: El tema de Atom lo solucione creando a mano los directorios `data\` y `html`. Ahora el problema est en que por tema de permisos no consigue contactar con la base de datos, la cual devuelve `Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`. Igualmente no puedo entrar por problema de permisos con DBeaver ala BD

Answer (score 2):

Si no he entendido mal, el problema es que los ficheros se crean con usuarios que no corresponden al tuyo, de ahí el problema de permisos para poder editar. Lo solucionas creando los directorios pero los ficheros creados por docker se siguen creando con otro usuario.

Docker crea los ficheros como usuario `root` a no ser que se le indique otro. Lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar con el parámetro `--user` indicando tu usuario:

```
--user $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

Como dices que lo ejecutas con `docker-compose`, le has de pasar los datos como una variable. Añade en tus servicios:

```
[...]
ps:
depends_on:
  - db
container_name: ps-web
user: ${USER_ID}
      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

y ejecuta con

```
USER_ID=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up
```

Ahora los ficheros creados por docker deberían pertenecer a tu usuario y por tanto tener acceso completo a ellos.